# Clearing out Sinatra Assetpack asset pipeline

Tags: asset-pipeline, sinatra-assetpack

I'm playing around [with](https://github.com/timwingfield/backbone-sinatra-boilerplate) this package of Sinatra and Coffeescript and can't seem to clear the asset pipeline. When I update backbone.js to the most recent version, the app (run with `shotgun watch`) continues to serve the version of backbone.js that I've just replaced!

I am sure there is a rake command or something to clear the asset pack, but I cannot find it in any of the documentation.

`rake assets:clean` is telling me that rake doesn't know that task.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you aren't [cache busting](http://www.adopsinsider.com/ad-ops-basics/what-is-a-cache-buster-and-how-does-it-work/) properly. Have you looked into using [Sinatra Asset Pack](http://ricostacruz.com/sinatra-assetpack/) for your asset management? It has support for coffescript and will automatically bust your cache so new changes will be recognized right away.

Another option is to just clear your cache with a hardreload, shift+f5 or clear it manually in your browser.